# mysql- Prevent id increment on unique

Tags: mysql

I have a table with unique constraint, which is working fine.
But the problem is when a duplicate record is tried to be inserted it fails due to unique constraint but, increments the id and next valid record get the id with double increment.
How to prevent id from incrementing if insertion fails?

**UPDATE**
 Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `crawl_links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_crawled_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `crawl_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'New',
  `server_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_name_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_fetched_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

NOTE: I have taken this from dump file created

I have a links database. I collect links from a crawler and store it in the db. The links collected can be duplicate. So to prevent, I added UNIQ constraint on url field. The constraint is successfully preventing the insertion of duplicate records. But however it increments the id even if the insert is failed. My id column is INT(11) and current snapshot of my db shows `max(id) = 128961841` but number of records `count(*) crawl_links = 700231`.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on your id column  being gapless.

Comment: The problem is in your design , not in db - try to review design, so any step between IDs will not cause the problem

Comment: The purpose of `AUTO_INCREMENT` is to provide unique identifiers, not a sequence. You cannot rely on it to provide a gapless sequence. If you need a gapless sequence for something, implement it yourself.

Comment: @dan: I dont really need a gapless sequence. I just want to stop id increment on failed insert.

Comment: There's no reason to want that except to have a gapless sequence. "I just want" without a reason is not a valid thought to have.

Comment: @dan: Adding the reason above ;)

Comment: @Pravin I see your update, but I still don't see a reason to want to change the behavior of auto_increment. Why do you care that `max(id)` is 128961841 or any other number?

Comment: @dan: I feel it will exceed the limit rapidly, Isn't it? And is it the normal behavior to auto increment the id on failed insert? I am actually confused about the increment on failure.

Comment: @Pravin If you make the column a bigint, you're many orders of magnitude away from any limits. You *could* drop the artificial key altogether and make something like an md5 hash of the URL the primary key of the row.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - I agree to SergeS, in general it should not matter at all if there are gaps between the ids.
But still I am curious, since I never had such behavior, so I tried to reproduce:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( 
 id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment, 
 bar CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY( id ), 
 UNIQUE( bar ) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo SET bar = 'a';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo SET bar = 'a';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'a' for key 2
mysql> INSERT INTO foo SET bar = 'b';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+----+-----+
| id | bar |
+----+-----+
|  1 | a   | 
|  2 | b   | 
+----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried with InnoDB and MyISAM but was not able to build gaps that way. Could you please describe your table setup and your insert?

Comment: I have added table structure above..
I am using it in a rails application.

Comment: `INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in some cases can cause `AUTO_INCREMENT` to increment despite a new row not being inserted. It does happen.

Answer (score -2):

There is a command to manually set the next ID to be used:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

You'll probably have to check if the last INSERT falied due to violation of the UNIQUE contraint, then apply the query above when necessary.